# Object as a source for the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an object submission which contains some informations which I would like to show in a list view.

For example, in my object I can do this:

```
submission.firstElement().getDate()
```

and

```
submission.firstElement().getTitle()
```

which returns me a date and a title.

My problem is: how to show those two elements (not only the first's) in a listview (two elements per list item).

I have thinked on a for loop with the submission.size() but I have no idea how to get forward with.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at using a ListView and a ArrayAdapter. You could use a BaseAdapter  but I have found a ArrayAdapter more than adequate for displaying a list of custom objects in a ListView.

First create a layout that will be used to show the desired data per row in the ListView. In your case I assume that it will be two TextViews, one showing the title and date.

Once done, create a ListAdapter and in it's constructor give it the layout for the row created above. Once done, use the getView() function to access the layout and populate the TextView's with the object's date and title.

Have a look at the following links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

EDIT:

Ana, to aid you a bit further use a ListActivity as shown in this Google documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. In the example given they use  a SimpleListAdapter. However, for an ArrayAdapter the constructor is a little simpler:

```
new ArrayListAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, listOfObjects);
```

When using a ListActivity a layout does not need to be created as by default it includes one.

Comment: Thank you @Richard, I will try to do this. I have allready my ArrayAdapter but how to create the layout with which i could show the desired data per row?

Comment: Create the layout like you would when creating a layout for an activity/fragment. If using Eclipse, create a new layout XML file and use the visual editor to drag and drop two TextView's onto it into the desired position. Then, rather that using it in a setContentView() method, pass it to the constructor. Is this what you mean by "how" to create one?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, no, it was not exactly my question. I would like to know how to create my listview with the two data per row.

Comment: Ana, I have added extra info in the answer which I hope will help you out further.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Richard, I have found the solution by using the example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx